# Implementing permessage-deflate in WebSockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, compression, deflate, inflate

I hava a problem understanding and implementing a permessage-deflate extension in WebSockets.

So far, I have added 'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate' inside handshake code. It seems to work all fine.

However when I send a "TEST" message from the server (Node.js) to the Client (JS), it seems that the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) is not decompressing the data itself.

How to properly implement data compression and decompression using permessage-deflate extension?

Request Header:

```
GET ws://localhost/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Sec-WebSocket-Key: X3RofjiYbzVR8zUPI5ZI6w==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: Exodus_101
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
sec-websocket-accept: sFO1Id30BZe63QWcm894hnnb+Pg=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: Exodus_101
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
```

Comment: copy and paste the handshake negotiation

Comment: @vtortola Hi! I just edited the post above. I have included the headers.

Comment: Handshake seems to be ok, How are you compressing and decompressing?

Comment: I'm not, I thought the whole compressing and decompressing functionality will happen automatically when adding permessage-deflate in to the header. My problem is the understanding of how to implement compressing and decompressing.

Comment: Humm.. You have to actually enable something in node.js or add an extension for that to happen, not just return a header.

Answer (score 9):

Both, the server and the client compresses the payload data portion
   of WebSocket data messages on a per-message basis using parameters
   negotiated during the opening handshake

**permessage-deflate** header is used in the handshake to indicate whether a connection should use compression.

1. When a client sends a websocket request, it send's **permessage-deflate**  in the websocket extensions header IF the client browser supports it. The server knows if a client supports compression based on this header.
2. If the server decides to use compression, it responds with the same header similar to an ACK message. The client after receiving the response decides whether or not to compress the data based on the server's response.

Once both the sever and the client decides to use compression, they individually have to compress the message using deflate compression technique.
i.e You'll have to enable compression on the server by using the **"perMessageDeflate"** option while creating the websocket server. the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) node module enables this by default. The ws module takes care of the header flags so that you don't need to implicitly set it.

> Note: Deflate uses a combination of LZ77 and Huffman coding to compress
>   data.The **client_max_window_bits**; **server_max_window_bits=10** header flags are used to set a custom buffer/'sliding window' used by the LZ77 algorithm to decrease memory overhead.

Comment: A minor correction: The ws node module supports the permessage-deflate extension but it enables it by default only on the client. It is turned off on the server by default and the recommendation is that we turn it on only after testing it on a representative workload as it has a significant impact both on CPU and memory