# Are websocket frames automatically compressed after adding the permessage-deflate response header?

Tags: compression

**The bottom line:**

I don't see websocket messages compressed, even though the permessage-deflate headers exist on both request and response.

**Some details:**

I have a nodejs server, and I use Primus (with engine.io under).
I use the 'compression' feature of Primus, in order to support permessage-delate.

After I turn it on, I start seeing permessage-deflate header on responses.

But I don't see the websocket frames themselves being compressed.

I sniff the traffic using charlesproxy, and again - the frames look the same as they were before I turned the 'compression' feature on.

**Illustration:**

Here's an example request from the websocket handshake:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie:[some cookies]
Host:[our host]
Origin:https://[our host]
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:6nMxnGd0E8GrDg2s1B4tHQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

And this is the corresponding response:

```
Connection:upgrade
Date:Tue, 11 Jul 2017 14:10:18 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:lLjOXWbLRVIHw2inxrhx0U1ryrM=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_no_context_takeover
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Server:nginx
Upgrade:websocket
WebSocket-Server:uWebSockets
```

These examples are taken from the Chrome dev tools network inspector.
I see something similar in the charlesproxy sniffer.

**Other reference:**

I saw this:

[Implementing permessage-deflate in WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348348/implementing-permessage-deflate-in-websockets)

But I couldn't quite find an valid answer there.

**So...**

What am I missing here?
Do I need to implement something more?
Do I need to include any library?

**Versions:**

- node - 4.2.4
- primus - 7.0.2
- chrome: 59.0.3071.115
- FF: 54.0.1
- charles: 4.1.4

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `uws` does not compress data even if it is instructed to do so.

See this issue https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/issues/474

It should work if you tell `engine.io` to use `ws` instead of `uws`. You can do that by setting the `EIO_WS_ENGINE` env variable to `ws` or using the `wsEngine` option of `engine.io`.

I think there is also a size threshold under which messages are not compressed. If I'm not wrong it's 1 KiB.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

In the charlesproxy sniffer - I found where to see a view of the compressed data (to those who want to know - I looked at the view of the wss, which breaks down the websocket frames. The compressed data can be seen on the http/https entry, which represents the websocket handshake, and has a 'compressed' tab).

I guess the network sniffer of Chrome dev tools simply shows the data after compression, so it's human readable.

To answer my own question, I don't think I need to implement something further in order to have the data compressed.