# How to solve Web Sockets error crashing Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket

I have a problem with my Vue app where I cannot get a page to load due to the app crashing. This is the error that shows in the console. I am not really sure why this error is happening because there is no implementation of Web Sockets currently on the app.

I have also added this to the webpack config but it has not resloved ths problem.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    // other devServer options
    webSocketServer: 'none'
  }
  
};
```

This is the main part of the error.

```
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear
```

If anyone has any ideas where this error might be coming from I'd really appreciate the help.

**EDIT**
I am able to run the app and receive the following in the console:

```
 App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.0.147:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

The web socket error appears when I try to navigate to another view.

Comment: WS is used for hot reload by webpack devserver. It's unknown what's your setup and what the problem could be. Could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77296871/ or  countless other reasons. "This is the main part of the error" - what is the rest? Please, don't truncate the relevant info

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port from 8080, which seemed to be the default for Web Sockets in my case,fixed this issue for me.

I put a new default port in the `package.json` scripts and the app loaded fine.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3001",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
```

I don't know what the problem was with Web Sockets itself but my app isn't using WS so I just went with the port change.